# How to obtain video url from social networks

Tags: api, flutter, dart

I want to make a video downloader app with support for as many networks as possible.

I managed to get a nice json response from Instagram, it basically works by adding ?__a=1 at the end of post link. In that json there is also source of video in that post which can be then downloaded.

But I can't find anything like this for other networks, like Facebook or TikTok... Facebook is asking me to register for key or some token, which is kind of a annoying if I have to do it for every network..

So is there some convenient way of getting video urls from social networks post's? Something like Instagram is offering? I don't get it how other apps of this type are doing it...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there's no easy way of doing this because it's against most social media platform's privacy policy. I mean, you could do it running a Cloud Function with Puppeteer and scraping the links directly from the page, but it could easily get you banned from the platform, you would have to check out their policies on that.
Hope you find this helpful!